# Query entries based on date's year

Tags: entries

I'm trying to pull all events where the event's year from `endDate` matches the queried year (`yearParam`). When I have this, it's pulling in all events before the `yearParam`:

```
{% set pastEntries = craft.entries({endDate: '<' ~ yearParam}).section('events').order('endDate desc') %}
```

However, what I'd really like is to get entries that match the `yearParam` (so if the yearParam is 2017, then any events from 2017 should be pulled in).

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If I'm following you correctly, wouldn't `{endDate: '=' ~ yearParam}` or `{endDate: yearParam}` do what you're looking for?

Comment: That did it, @denesis. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Filtering entries by year with pagination example:

```
{% set query = craft.request.getQuery() %}
{% set selectedYear = query.year is defined ? query.year|abs : FALSE %}

{% paginate craft.entries({
   section: 'news',
   postDate: '>=' ~ selectedYear,
   postDate: '<' ~ (selectedYear + 1)
}).limit(12) as pageInfo, newsEntries %}
```

Comment: This will not work, because the 2nd postDate condition overwrites the first. Try something like that:  
`postDate: ([ 'and', '>= ' ~ selectedYear, '< ' ~ (selectedYear + 1) ]),`.
Sorry for the bad code formatting.